# How to count number of rows, not count within each row

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL, which gets me the number of distinct `hit_ids` in my table:

```
select hit_id from mturk_completion group by hit_id
```

How would I then get the number of rows returned? (In my case it should be 25). In doing a `COUNT` it seems to be return a count for **each** of the 25 rows:

```
select COUNT(hit_id) from mturk_completion group by hit_id

22
10
6
2
6
etc.
```

How would I get just the number of rows returned, 25 in this case?

Comment: What happens if you just drop `group by hit_id` from the latter query?

Comment: @mopo922 It would count up all the rows (317) instead of just the distinct entries (25). I figured out how to do it, in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me, using `DISTINCT` instead of the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(hit_id)) FROM mturk_completion
```